# Google Data Fusion Salesforce to Bigquery Pipeline, automatic way of managing schema updates in Salesforce

Tags: google-bigquery, salesforce, google-cloud-data-fusion

Hey I am trying to create some batch jobs that reads from a couple Salesforce Objects and pushes them to BQ. Every-time batch process runs it will truncate the table in BQ and push all the data in the SF object back into BQ. Is it possible for google data fusion to automatically detect changes in an object in Salesforce(like adding a new column or changing data types of a column) then be registered and pushed to BQ via google data fusion?

Comment: Hi OP, can you provide sample code of your batch job, sample data and sample output/illustration for your use case for more accurate replication?

Answer (score 0):

For SF side of the puzzle you could look into https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_describeGlobal.htm and `If-Modified-Since` header telling you if the definition of table(s) changed. That url is for all tables in the org or you run table-specific metadata describe calls with https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_sobject_describe.htm

But I can't tell you how to use it in your job.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the provided answer of @eyescream to be the `condition` or the `trigger` for the update to BigQuery. You may push changes to BigQuery using the pre-built plugin **Stream Source** approach from Datafusion in which, as mentioned in this [docmentation](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/data-analytics/load-salesforce-data-to-bigquery-with-cloud-data-fusion), it

> tracks updates in Salesforce sObjects. Examples of sObjects are
> opportunities, contacts, accounts, leads, any custom object, etc.

You may use this approach to automatically track changes and push them to BigQuery. You can also find the whole **Salesforce Streaming Source** configuration reference in this [documentation](https://github.com/data-integrations/salesforce/blob/develop/docs/Salesforce-streamingsource.md#salesforce-streaming-source) as also redirected from google's official documentation.

However, if you want a more dynamic approach for your overall use case, you may also use the [integration of BigQuery with Salesforce](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2018/08/integrate-google-bigquery-with-salesforce). However in this approach, you will need to build your own code in which you can also use @eyescream 's answer as the primary condition/trigger and then automatically push the update to your BigQuery schema.